# window is not defined when I add mobx store (server side rendering)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mobx, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to server side render my react app, everything was working fine till I added a mobx store, it's giving me this error

[screenshot of the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UO9Sh.png)

Comment: You can use the stacktrace to see the undefined `window` reference. The `server.js:186:2` means that line 186 of your `server.js` is referencing `window` incorrectly.

Comment: On the server, there is no window, that's only available in the browser

Comment: Sorry, I posted the wrong screenshot, now it's updated